# Weird behaviour of Hoeffding's lemma/inequality for $a=0,b=1$

Tags: inequality, solution-verification, random-variables, proof-explanation, expected-value

I was trying to prove hoeffding's inequality and found wikipedia articles for the [lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hoeffding%27s_lemma) and the [inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hoeffding%27s_inequality) itself
I am interested in the case when $X_i\in[0,1]$ and found this strange behaviour. I was trying to reproduce the proof. My go:

> **Hoeffding's Lemma.** Let $X$ be a random variable with $X\in[0,1]$, then for any $\lambda \in\mathbb{R}$ we have $\operatorname{E}[e^{\lambda (X-\operatorname{E}[X]}]\leq e^{\lambda^2/8}$

> *Proof.* Since $f(x)=e^{\lambda x}$ is convex function for any $\lambda\in\mathbb{R}$, then the line connecting points $(0,f(0)),(1,f(1))$ is above $f(x)$, i.e. for any $x\in[0,1]$ we have
> $$
> e^{\lambda x} \leq e^{\lambda \cdot 0}(1-x)+xe^{\lambda \cdot 1}=1-x+xe^{\lambda}
> $$
> plugging in $X-\operatorname{E}[X]$ for $x$:
> $$
>  e^{\lambda(X-\operatorname{E}[X])}\leq 1-X+\operatorname{E}[X]+(X-\operatorname{E}[X])e^{\lambda}
> $$
> and taking expectation on both sides we get
> $$
>  \operatorname{E}[e^{\lambda (X-\operatorname{E}[X])}]\leq 1
> $$

now this is really weird. Now I tried to prove the Hoeffding inequality in this form:

> **Theorem.** Let $X_i$ be independent random variables with $X_i\in[0,1]$, $X=\sum_iX_i$ and let $\varepsilon > 0$. Then
> $$
> \operatorname{P}[X-\operatorname{E}[X]\geq \varepsilon] \leq e^{-2\varepsilon^2/n}
> $$

Now I proceeded with the proof: (what wikipedia denotes $s,t$ respectively, I denote $\lambda,\varepsilon$, respectively) Now I get:

> *Proof.*
> \begin{align}
> \operatorname{P}[X-\operatorname{E}[X]\geq \varepsilon]&=\operatorname{P}[e^{\lambda(X-\operatorname{E}[X])}\geq e^{\lambda \varepsilon}] \leq \\&\leq \frac{\operatorname{E}[e^{\lambda (X-\operatorname{E}[X])}]}{e^{\lambda \varepsilon}}=\\&=\frac{\prod_{i=1}^n\operatorname{E}[e^{\lambda (X_i-\operatorname{E}[X_i])}]}{e^{\lambda \varepsilon}}\leq \\&\leq e^{-\lambda \varepsilon}
> \end{align}

In this step $\lambda$ is still to be chosen, but both $\varepsilon,\lambda$ are positive in this case I can choose $\lambda$ artbitrarily large and get arbitrarily small upper bound, which is suspicious. I could particularly pick $\lambda = -2\varepsilon/n$ and be done, but It is still weird. Where is the mistake?

Comment: In the proof of the first Lemma you take x to be $X - E[X]$, but you don't know that this is an element of $[0,1]$.

Comment: aaah, yes. But for sure $X-EX$ is element of $[-1,1]$, right?

Comment: Yes, but I didn't check how your proof changes if you account for this (do it!)

Comment: It now coincides with the one given on wikipedia, had to be a bit careful, but I got it now.